# Jquery remove() not works with removeClass()

Tags: jquery, html, find, removeclass

I have a span which consist of 6 divs(4 resize, 1 rotate, 1 property box)

The following functionality i need when onclick button:

1. I need to removeClass() for first five(4 resize, 1 rotate) classes. - Works perfectly
2. I need to remove() last div (1 property box). - Not working

How to remove the last div from the span..? Please help me. Thanks in Advance...

#### Code which i used:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('button').on('click', function() 
    { 
        $('.workspace > span').find('div').removeClass();
        $('.workspace > span').find('div').eq(6).remove();
    });
});
```

My code in [JSfiddle..!](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/oqqbbgyj/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('.workspace > span').find('div').eq(6).remove();
```

Use(instead of `eq(6)` try `eq(5)`)

```
$('.workspace > span').find('div').eq(5).remove(); //eq indexing starts from 0.
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqqbbgyj/3/)

[Docs](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.workspace > span').find('div').eq(5).remove();
```

coz eq starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

> *I need to **remove() last div** (1 property box). - Not working*

use `.last()` as you don't have to calculate the index of the property div. But you have to ensure that property div is always the last div.:

```
$('.workspace > span').find('div').last().remove();
```